# Error while sending attachment to Soap web service

Tags: java, web-services, content-type, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

On running the example provided in the link https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/examples/org/apache/http/examples/entity/mime/ClientMultipartFormPost.java, I am getting the below exception

```
com.sun.xml.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=APQdLVD1_Zc9bPMSMCmGCk012pvQ6Yv Supported ones are: [text/xml]
```

Any idea why it is coming?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing two topics:

- A HTML form post
- A SOAP request post

In the former you indeed send a multipart/form-data as you seem to have done.
In the latter you generally don't send multiparts (unless you are using something like MTOM) but simply post the entire content as "application/soap+xml"

When using MTOM, you don't use multipart/form-data but multipart/related and you still need to follow some conventions that are not found in HTML and as such not in the example code you posted.